# Deferred pipeline execution in powershell?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

Is it possible to delay pipeline execution, or to modify a previous pipeline? What I am looking for is the ability to interact with an ODATA endpoint. I want to use standard (or custom) powershell commands to filter the data, but I don't want to retrieve the whole list. For example

```powershell
function Get-Records() {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $endpoint.Uri.AbsoluteUri ...
}
```

Calling this could return 500+ records. Normally I would not want to retrieve all 500 records, sometimes I would. So I might just call `Get-Records` if I need all 500. But if I only wanted specific ones I would want to do

```bsh
Get-Records | Where {$_.Name -eq 'me'}
```

The above still receives all 500 records and then filters them down. I would somehow want the `Where {$_.Name -eq 'me'}` to instead pass back to the previous pipeline a filter to the `Invoke-RestMethod` and appending to the URI `$filter=Name eq 'me'`

Comment: i THINK you can use a `Select-Object` call after the `Where-Object` call to exit the pipeline as soon as the 1st matching object is sent out. do the filter in the `W-O` call, then use `Select-Object -First 1` to exit the pipeline.

Comment: Pass the filter as an optional argument to your `Get-Records` method.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey that may be true, but it still makes the request for all 500 records. There is even a possibility of some of these requesting 1M records. At that point I would look at using pagination, but if I only wanted 1 record I wouldn't want to request all 1M.

Comment: @esac - yep, that is the case with the code you posted. [*grin*] the only fix seems to be moving the filter into your custom code ... and that is beyond my skill level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify a pipeline retroactively via a post-processing filter such as `Where-Object`.

Instead, **you must filter *at the source*, using the *syntax of the data provider*.**

This is how PowerShell's built-in cmdlets such as `Get-ChildItem` do it, via a `[string]`-typed `-Filter` *parameter*.

**If you want to pass a PowerShell *script block* as the filter, you'll have to translate it to the provider's syntax yourself - *if possible***.

There will rarely be a one-to-one mapping of PowerShell expressions to a provider's filter capabilities, so **perhaps the better approach is to require the user to use the provider's syntax directly**:

```
function Get-Records() {
  param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory)]
   [uri] $Uri
   ,
   [string] $Filter # Optional filter in provider syntax; e.g. "Name eq 'me'"
  )
    if ($Filter) { $Uri += '?$filter=' + $Filter }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
}

# Invoke with a filter in the provider's syntax.
Get-Records "Name eq 'me'"
```

---

**If you do want the user to be able to pass a script block, you'll have to do your own translation to the provider syntax and ensure that translation is possible.**

To do this robustly, you'd have to process the script block's AST (abstract syntax tree), which is accessible via its [`.Ast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.Ast) property, which is nontrivial.

If you're willing to make assumptions about the type of expressions a user is allowed to pass, you can get away with *string parsing*, such as in the following simplistic example:

---

```
function Get-Records {
  param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory)]
   [uri] $Uri
   ,
   [scriptblock] $FilterScriptBlock # Optional filter
  )
    if ($FilterScriptBlock) { 
      # Translate the script block' *string representation*
      # into the provider-native filter syntax.
      # Note: This is overly simplistic in that it simply removes '$_.'
      #       and '-' before '-eq'.
      $Uri += '?$filter=' + $FilterScriptBlock -replace '\$_\.' -replace '-(?=[a-z]+\b)'
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $Uri
}

# Invoke with a filter specified as a PowerShell script block.
Get-Records { $_.Name -eq 'me' }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am currently doing it the first way, the 2nd way seems like an option to me. Using pipelining it seems like I could get close by having the base request just return the URI and pipeline it into Get-Records which could so the filtering, and then finally process it. So something like `Build-Request -Uri .. | Get-Records { $_.Name -eq 'me' } | Process-Request`. It would be nice if `Build-Request` or `Get-Records` could detect if there are anymore items in the pipeline, and the last one could just do the `Process-Request` but this is clean.

Comment: Found a way to check if it is the last item in the pipeline.

Comment: @esac Yes, you can test `$MyInvocation.PipelinePosition -eq $MyInvocation.PipelineLength` inside a function, but I wouldn't use that approach, because such situationally different behavior can be confusing. Instead, I would do it all with a single function with a mandatory URI parameter and an optional filter parameter - please see my update.